# Get the url Parameter string from Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, url, parameters, uri

I  need the whole parameter list as such , not one by one

var Url = "http://localhost/Home/Admin?param1=1&param2=2$param3=3";

I want to get the whole parameter list from the url.

```
var params = "param1=1&param2=2&param3=3";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: What have  you tried, anyway?

Comment: `Url.split('?')[1]` or `Url.slice(Url.lastIndexOf('?') + 1)`

Comment: `var params = Url.split('?')[1];`

Comment: Is there a $ in url??

Comment: @RiteshKashyap sorry, no $ , just a typing mistake

Comment: @nicael  not duplicate , I dont need values single single, I need the whole parameters as one, for using in history.push method

Comment: @PranavCBalan this is a lot simpler to use , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Url = "http://localhost/Home/Admin?param1=1&param2=2$param3=3";
var urlArray = url.split("?");
var params=urlArray[1];
```

You can see [Using split() example of Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for more insight on using the split function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support, I use this one for my need

```
var params = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
```